# Превратить дифференциальное уравнение в систему ОДУ первого порядка

Tags: математика

У нас есть дифференциальное уравнение вида **x''' = f(t, x, x'')** и его надо превратить в систему ОДУ первого порядка. Понимаю что скорее всего сайт не очень предназначен для таких вопросов, но где еще это можно спросить не знаю.

Идей по решению вообще нет. Буду благодарен если распишите ответ по решению таких заданий

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это очень просто. Вводите пару новых переменных, и - вуаля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]